# Why $\frac{1}{x}$ is not Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$ but $\ln{x}$ is?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

In *Rene Schilling - Measures, Integrals and Martingales*, on page 94, Theorem 11.8 states that:

> A bounded function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if, and only if, the
>   points in $(a,b)$ where f is discontinuous are a Lebesgue null set.

Well, then I don't really understand why the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ (of course I actually do, cause it is not bounded there) but $g(x)=\ln{x}$ is.

Why is happening this? $g$ is unbounded in the same interval but still Riemann integrable (it's integral is -1)

Which differs from $f$ to $g$?

Comment: Neither is Riemann integrable, as both are unbounded. But $\ln x$ is improperly integrable, while $1/x$ is not. This is because the limit $\lim_{t\to1}\int_t^1f(x)\,dx$ converges for $f(x)=\ln x$ but diverges for $f(x)=1/x$.

Comment: Do you understand why the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges but the series $\sum 2^{-n}$ converges? The question is not **whether** the terms go to zero, but the **rate** that they go do zero.  In your case, the question is not **whether** $|f|$ is unbounded, but the **rate** it goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes i know it but I wanted to see it in terms of Lebesgue and Riemann integrability conditions. So, for example, what can we say about $\int_{[0,1]}|\ln{x}|dx$ in Lebesgue sense? it is integrable? it is only improperly integrable?

Comment: @Dani: It is integrable, simply because$|\ln x| = -\ln x$ and $\ln x$ does not change its sign and is Riemann integrable. In general, for (piecewise continuous) functions that do not change sign, Riemann integrability is equivalent to Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: @PhoemueX but in the first comment LordSharktheUnknown said that $\ln{x}$ is not Riemann integrable but improperly integrable. That's why I was wondering if $|\ln{x}|$ might be improperly Lebesgue integrable also

Comment: @Dani: Ok, I was not completely precise. For Lebesgue integrals, one usually does not define "improper" Lebesgue integrability. A measurable function is Lebesgue integrable iff $\int |f| dx <\infty$. Now, a piecewise continuous, locally bounded function on an open (possibly unbounded) interval $(a,b)$ which does not change its sign is  (improperly) Riemann integrable, if and only if it is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ok thank you so much. One more thing, can you tell me where can I find that information or some kind of proof for that? maybe a book, a website, whatever. Thanks!

Comment: @Dani: Good question. The first thing I found is Theorem 11.33 in "Baby Rudin" (Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis). There, it is shown that a bounded function on an interval is Riemann-Integrable if and only if the set of discontinuity-points forms a Lebesgue null-set, and then the two integrals coincide. The general claim then follows easily from properties of the Lebesgue integral and the definition of improper Riemann integrals (e.g. $\int_a^\infty f(x) d\lambda(x) = \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_a^t f(x) d \lambda(x) = \lim_t \int_a^t f(x) dx = \int_a^\infty f(x) dx$, ...

Comment: ... , where the first equality always holds if $f$ is measurable and does not change sign (lets say for simplicity that $f \geq 0$), for example by the monotone convergence theorem for the Lebesgue integral. Finally, the last equality also always holds, by definition of the improper Riemann integral (and we say the integral exists if and only if the limit exists).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101963/discussion-between-dani-and-phoemuex).